# Expected number of kitchens sold (Exercise 3.11.38 from Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability, proof-verification, proof-writing

A telephone sales company attempts repeatedly to sell new kitchens to each of the $N$ families in a village. Family $i$ agrees to buy a new kitchen after it has been solicited $K_i$ times, where the $K_i$ are independent identically distributed random variables with mass function $f(n) = P(K_i = n)$. The value $\infty$ is allowed, so that $f(\infty) \geq 0$. Let $X_n$ be the number of kitchens sold at the $n^\textrm{th}$ round of solicitations, so that
$$
X_n = \sum_{i=1}^N I_{\{K_i = n\}}.
$$
Suppose that $N$ is a random variable with the Poisson distribution parameter $v$.

(a) Show that the $X_n$ are independent random variables, $X_r$ having the Poisson distribution with parameter $vf(r)$.

(b) The company loses heart after the $T^\textrm{th}$ round of calls, where $T = \inf \{n : X_n = 0\}$. Let $S = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_T$ be the number of solicitations made up to time $T$. Show further that
$$
E(S) = v E(F(T))
$$
where $F(k) = f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(k)$.

I completed part (a) but I'm not sure whether my argument for part (b) is correct. I started the proof for part (b) as follows.
\begin{align}
E(S) &= \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} E(S | T = i) P(T = i) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} E\left(\sum_{t = 1}^i X_t\right) P(T = i) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} E(X_i) P(T \geq i) \\
&= \ldots
\end{align}

Although I am confident that the rest of the proof is correct, I am not sure if the first two lines above are correct? Do I need to justify that $E(S|T = i) = E\left(\sum_{t = 1}^i X_t\right)$?

Comment: You do not need to justify that.  It is correct.

Comment: To be precise, $T$ is a stopping time with respect to the natural filtration of $\{X_n\}$, so by Wald's identity $$\mathbb E[S_T] = \mathbb E[T]\mathbb E[X_1]. $$

Comment: @Math1000, It's similar to Wald's identity, but the $X_n$ aren't necessarily i.i.d.